# How can we bulk upload questions and answers to MYSQL database from Word document?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, math

I am trying to bulk upload questions and answers from a word document. which contains questions with answers like

[image: **I have attached the screenshot of model question paper**]

I am using the following PHP class

```
class Doc2Txt {
private $filename;

public function __construct($filePath) {
    $this->filename = $filePath;
}

private function read_doc() {
    $fileHandle = fopen($this->filename, "r");
    $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($this->filename));   
    $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
    $outtext = "";
    foreach($lines as $thisline)
      {
        $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
        if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
          {
          } else {
            $outtext .= $thisline." ";
          }
      }
     $outtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$outtext);
    return $outtext;
}

private function read_docx(){

    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';

    $zip = zip_open($this->filename);

    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);

    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}

public function convertToText() {

    if(isset($this->filename) && !file_exists($this->filename)) {
        return "File Not exists";
    }

    $fileArray = pathinfo($this->filename);
    $file_ext  = $fileArray['extension'];
    if($file_ext == "doc" || $file_ext == "docx")
    {
        if($file_ext == "doc") {
            return $this->read_doc();
        } else {
            return $this->read_docx();
        }
    } else {
        return "Invalid File Type";
    }
}
}
```

What is the procedure to save these type of mathematical data in the database? or Please let me know, how can I achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show us your code.

Comment: Try to save the document in html format then look at its source to find an algorithm by which you can parse it to obtain every question and its answers.

Comment: Better to use Excel.

Comment: @ColourDalnet I have updated the code here

Comment: @sємsєм Thanks, I am trying to find out the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

When we paste the mathematical formula in excel it is displayed properly but when we try pasting it in word or some other editors, the formula is changed to    E= A/(wt.of H_2  displaced)×E_H

so if we find the data conversion happening in excel, we can easily do that in MYSQL database too